# Names in the listbox

Tags: c#, button, listbox, windows-forms-designer

I need help with program, where I have a listbox with names and I need to check if there is more than 3 same names in the listbox when I press the buttonControl, the MessegeBox is displayed and it says "There are too many of the same names in the list as allowed". The code is like this for now:

```
private void buttonVlozjmeno_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
        string add_name = textBoxName.Text;
        if (index >= 0)
            listBox1.Items.Insert(index, add_name);
        else
            listBox1.Items.Add(add_name);
        textBoxJmeno.Text = null;
    }
    private void buttonADD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
        listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(index);
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add("Adam");
        listBox1.Items.Add("Adam");
        listBox1.Items.Add("Adam");
        listBox1.Items.Add("John");
        listBox1.Items.Add("John");
        listBox1.Items.Add("Eva");
        listBox1.Items.Add("John");
        listBox1.Items.Add("John");
    }
    private void buttonControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Filip, what is the question you are asking? please edit your post to make it clear what is your problem and what is your question.

Comment: Can you look at it now? Please

Answer (score 1):

You can try querying the box with a help of *Linq*, e.g. for *WinForms* it can be

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  bool tooManySameNames = myBox
    .Items
    .OfType<String>()
    .GroupBy(name => name)
    .Any(group => group.Count() > 3);
```